# Calcular inputs com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso fazer com que o **+index** funcione, pois é um sistema de geração de páginas com produtos embutidos. No caso, a cada produto inserido vai ter um `total0 + total1` e assim em diante. Porém, tem que ser em tempo real o valor!

```js
function Soma(){
    var soma = 0;
    $('#total'+index).each(function(){
        var valorItem = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(!isNaN(valorItem))
           soma += parseFloat(valorItem);
    });
  
    $('#final').val((soma).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  
  Total produto1: <input type="text" id="total0" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" id="total1" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final">
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução usando JavaScript puro com redução de código:

Para que o resultado seja atualizado em *tempo real mesmo*, eu sugiro usar `oninput` em vez de `onblur`, assim, o resultado é atualizado à medida em que algo é digitado nos dois campos. Ficando assim:

```
<form action="">
  Total produto1: <input type="text" oninput="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" oninput="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final">
</form>
```

Não é necessário colocar um `id` nos campos que receberão os valores. É possível capturar esses elementos apenas por um atributo que eles possuem em comum: `oninput="Soma()"`.

**Código final:**

```js
function Soma(){
    var soma = 0;
    var ipts = document.querySelectorAll('input[oninput="Soma()"]');
    for(var x=0; x<ipts.length; x++){
       var valorItem = parseFloat(ipts[x].value);
       !isNaN(valorItem) ? soma += parseFloat(valorItem) : null;
    }
    document.querySelector('#final').value = soma.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  Total produto1: <input type="text" oninput="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" oninput="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o seu problema se resolve colocando uma classe nos inputs de total.

```js
function Soma(){

        var soma = 0;
        $('.totais').each(function(){
        var valorItem = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(!isNaN(valorItem))
        soma += parseFloat(valorItem);
    });
  
    $('#final').val((soma).toFixed(2));
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  
  Total produto1: <input type="text" class="totais" id="total0" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" class="totais" id="total1" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final">
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo adicionando um atributo [somar] para facilitar no selector.

```js
function Soma(){

    var soma = 0;
    $('input[somar="true"]').each(function(index){
          var valorItem = parseFloat($(this).val());
          if(!isNaN(valorItem))
          soma += parseFloat(valorItem);
    });
  
    $('#final').val((soma).toFixed(2));
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  
  Total produto1: <input type="text" id="total0" somar="true" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" id="total1" somar="true" onblur="Soma()" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final">
  
</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigadãoo eu só tive que alterar para a class pois o name vou utilizar para o método POST.

Comment: não recomendo utilizar a class, por que essa seria reservada para indicar uma classe de estilo no css, você pode utilizar qualquer outro atributo customizado e arbitrário. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: Fico no aguardo então, a principio já funcionou, apesar que eu não vou usar a class mesmo pois já utilizo o bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

O calculo em tempo real pode ser resolvido assim:

```
<form action="">

  Total produto1: <input type="text" id="total0" value="0"><br>
  Total produto2: <input type="text" id="total1" value="0"><br>
  <br>
  Total todos os produtos: <input type="text" id="final" value="0">

</form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#total0,#total1").keyup(function(){
     var total0 = $("#total0").val();
     var total1 = $("#total1").val();
     var total_geral = parseInt(total0)+parseInt(total1);
        $("#final").val(total_geral);
   });

 });
</script>
```